# Drupal 8, very simple hierarchical form doesn't work

Tags: forms, 8

In a custom module, I create a new form. In the buildForm function, I define my form :

```
$form["planet"] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => '1 : '.$this->t('planet'),
  '#maxlength' => 64,
  '#size' => 64,
  '#tree' => TRUE,
);

$form["planet"][0] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => '0 : '.$this->t('land'),
  '#maxlength' => 64,
  '#size' => 64,
);

$form["planet"][1] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => '1 : '.$this->t('land'),
  '#maxlength' => 64,
  '#size' => 64,
);

$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Submit'),
);
```

There are 3 fields, but this is the result :

[image]

Why there only first field displayed ?

Comment: I am not certain you would be able to render a textfield within a textfield, ie `$form["planet"][0]` within `$form["planet"]`, what do you need to achieve with the 'hierarchical' aspect of the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need change type **$form["planet"]** to **fieldset** or **container**. Don't use text field in this case:

```
$form["planet"] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => '1 : '.$this->t('planet'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE, 
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,
);
```